# FormDataCollection not working in ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

Don't check it with Core 1.1 or 2.0.
Situation is when using **FormDataCollection** as parameter in controller method like this:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("user")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage CheckUser(FormDataCollection form)
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

It returns **400 Bad Request** no matter whan Content-Type header.

But it works in .NET Framework 4.5:

```
[RoutePrefix("auth")]
public class AuthController : ApiController
{
    [Route("user")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage user(FormDataCollection form)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course I can use `Request.Form.TryGetValue(key, out var value)`. But class **FormDataCollection** is not depricated in Core and I'm curious can (and should) we use it to get post parameters?

Comment: Did it *ever* work? Actions accept either DTOs or explicit parameters. Using a bucket like FormDataCollection` defeats the very purpose of MVCs data-binding

Comment: Why did you use `FormDataCollection` at all? If you used a DTO it would be instantiated from the body. If you want to bind simple parameters to the *body*, use `[FromBody] `

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos just found it in one repo witch is for 4.5 framework and wanted convert it to NET Core. And it's not MVC actually, its API. And formally it doesn't know model of DTO.

Comment: And you shouldn't try random code. You won't find that class in the docs, tutorials or courses. Go through the tutorials in the [ASP.NET documentation site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/) to understand how Web API actually works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FormDataCollection** that is shipped with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim **does not have parameterless constructor**, so this would be the cause of the issue. As per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1) -

> In order for binding to happen the class must have a public default
>   constructor and member to be bound must be public writable properties.
>   When model binding happens the class will only be instantiated using
>   the public default constructor, then the properties can be set.

Comment: I looked at **FormDataCollection** in Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client. But you are right it doesn't have parameterless constructor. So what is its use case?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by use case? in asp.net core?

Comment: Yes, in asp.net core.

Comment: @xneg As per official doc on binding in asp.net core - "In order for binding to happen the class must have a public default constructor and member to be bound must be public writable properties. When model binding happens the class will only be instantiated using the public default constructor, then the properties can be set." It seems to me like it's something that was ported for the backward-compatibility, like in case you have lots of code using FormDataCollection.

Comment: ah, thank you. Backward-compatibility seems reasonable. Will accept your answer.

Comment: @xneg I'm glad I could help